# How to add see password icon just for chrome and Firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, passwords, microsoft-edge

I implemented a see password button for my password input using html and jquery so when I run it in Microsoft Edge and IE the browsers themselves have one button as default to see password for **type=password** inputs. and the result will be two see password button!

[image: as this image]

Now I have 3 solution I think!

**1. Disable Edge and IE see password default button (How?)**

**2. Disable my see password Button in Edge and IE (How?)**

**3. Enable same option for chrome and Firefox (How?)**

the third solution is the best i think. does chrome and Firefox have default see password button? If they have how can i use them?

Here is my code:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password " name="password">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button id="show_password" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" style="padding:9px;">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
</button>
</span>

<script>
$('#show_password').hover(function functionName() {
    //Change the attribute to text
    $('#password').attr('type', 'text');
    $('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-eye-open').addClass('glyphicon-eye-close');
}, function () {
    //Change the attribute back to password
    $('#password').attr('type', 'password');
    $('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-eye-close').addClass('glyphicon-eye-open');
}
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use position:absolute for view button.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  padding-right: 2.4em;
  height: 2em;
}

input::-ms-reveal {
  display: none;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 100;
}

span svg {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: .2em;
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="password">
  <span>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12.015 7c4.751 0 8.063 3.012 9.504 4.636-1.401 1.837-4.713 5.364-9.504 5.364-4.42 0-7.93-3.536-9.478-5.407 1.493-1.647 4.817-4.593 9.478-4.593zm0-2c-7.569 0-12.015 6.551-12.015 6.551s4.835 7.449 12.015 7.449c7.733 0 11.985-7.449 11.985-7.449s-4.291-6.551-11.985-6.551zm-.015 3c-2.209 0-4 1.792-4 4 0 2.209 1.791 4 4 4s4-1.791 4-4c0-2.208-1.791-4-4-4z"/></svg>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: @ImanFakhari You do not need to remove the standard password display button in the browser, you need to draw your own over it. this is the solution to the problem of duplicating buttons.

Comment: excellent solution! but Andrey please add background-color:white for span (for whom using png) and change input padding-right to 0.because Edge icon can not locate in on padding. and making padding for input make the icon next to my image. thanks

Comment: The major problem with this implementation is that Edge's "see password" icon is *better*.  It would be preferable to let the browser feature override (especially if Chrome adds it in the future!), and only add the JavaScript button as a backup plan.

Comment: Using the native functionality is usually a great idea, however, in IE11 and Edge (85) the password reveal icon/button is not always shown. For example, after entering text in the field, then leaving the field, then reentering, the ability to reveal the field's text is gone. The content can be manually deleted, then the field must lose and regain focus for the ability to be reenabled. This may or may not be acceptable and known behavior to the user, and may have UX/Security benefits, but may also be a valid reason for disabling the native behavior and implementing your own.

Answer (score 7):

For a pure css version you can use the IE10+ and edge pseudo-element [::-ms-reveal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-reveal)

```
input::-ms-reveal {
  display:none;
}
```

It also can be used to change the color or background

Answer (score 0):

- [Detect whic browser the user is using (click here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)
- if it's Edge or IE, add `visibility: hidden;` CSS property to your button

Code:

```js
$('#show_password').on("mousedown", function functionName() {
    //Change the attribute to text
    $('#password').attr('type', 'text');
    $('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-eye-open').addClass('glyphicon-eye-close');
}).on("mouseup", function () {
    //Change the attribute back to password
    $('#password').attr('type', 'password');
    $('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-eye-close').addClass('glyphicon-eye-open');
}
);

var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
var showButton = !(isIE || isEdge)
if (!showButton) {
    document.getElementById("show_password").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>example</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password " name="password">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button id="show_password" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" style="padding:9px;">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
</button>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Hold mouse down on the button to show the password.

Comment: Good solution. Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason for this to be downvoted? Is it a bad solution?

Comment: Bug: Press the button, move the mouse outside of the button and then release the button.